# Multiple POST request issues in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, forms, post

so I have been building a web app and I have already implemented a POST request to request some JSON data to be sent to the Node JS server however when I try to add a second post for a different set of data now as an HTML form I receive a Cannot POST /x/ page, however, if I use the previous POST URL for the first set of data the data is sent correctly. Is there some issue with sending multiple POST requests? I have added some code below so you can see my working /foo/ JSON data request vs my non-working /basket/ HTML form request. Thanks a lot in advance.

Working Code:

```
    app.post("/foo/", function(req, res) {

    var myObject = req.body;

    console.log(myObject);

    for(var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++){
        var parsed = JSON.parse(myObject[i])
        console.log(parsed.Item.ProductNo);
        console.log(parsed.Item.Quantity);
    }

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: '*****',
  auth: {
    user: '*****',
    pass: '*****'
  }
});
```

Not working request:

```
    app.post("/basket/"), function(req, res){
    var body = req.body;
    console.log(body);
}
```

Working foo request JS:

```
function sendBasket(){

    fetch('/foo/', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: localStorage.getItem('basket')
}).then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));

    console.log('Sending' + basketList + 'To email');
    //console.log(localStorage.getItem('basket'));
    //$.post("/foo/", localStorage.getItem('basket'), function(temp) {
    // temp === "I am done";    
//});


}
```

Not working HTML form request:

```
form#customerForm(method = 'post' action = '/basket/')
            input(class='input' id='email' name='email' type='email' value='')
            ul#listForBasket.listForBasket
            input#butSubmit(type = 'submit' value = 'submit')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I'm still somewhat unsure how I fixed it but the issue has now been resolved, I believe it was due to the incorrect use of the Action attribute in the HTML form along with a badly structured fetch request in the JS file and also a badly structured server.js file. Huge thanks to u/fastidious-magician for being a great help in diagnosing my issues. Here is my final working second fetch request in JS:

```
function sendData(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const bodyToSubmit = { "email": email }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(bodyToSubmit))
    fetch('/foo2/', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
          body: JSON.stringify(bodyToSubmit)
            }).then(res=>res.json())
              .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```